# MySQL to display earliest duplicate based on given parameters

Tags: bash, mysql, sql

What I need to have the statement do is:

1. From the name, output duplicate data with the earliest date.

For example:

If there is mich.edu with date 4/2/2012 and mich.edu with date 4/1/2012, I want the statement to only output mich.edu 4/1/2012

Here is my statement:

```
echo "select name, reported_at from nodes where reported_at < curdate() or reported_at is null;" | mysql dashboard
```

Current Output:

```
name            reported_at
ngsghsdfg.edu   2012-03-23 03:40:04
wasdfas.edu 2012-03-05 17:42:03
cnadfafg.uiowa.edu  NULL
qwerqwer.edu    2012-03-19 17:03:03
qwerqwre.edu    2012-03-30 20:04:02
qewrqwre.uiowa.edu  2012-03-24 16:10:02
qwerqewr.edu    2012-03-23 22:12:05
qwrewqreq.uiowa.edu NULL
qwerwqer.edu    2012-04-01 04:18:05
adfgnafg.edu    2012-03-27 18:21:01
adsfasf.edu         NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [`min()` aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min):

```
echo "select name, min(reported_at) from nodes where reported_at < curdate() or reported_at is null group by name;" | 
mysql dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, reported_at from nodes where reported_at < curdate() or reported_at is null order by reported_at desc group by name ;
```

might also work for you, since order by compares the dates, not the strings (min does that yet)

Comment: The `order by` clause should be _after_ the `group by` clause.